# Where should I subscribe firebase fetch items

Tags: react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-redux

im building an react native with redux and Firebase Realtime Database, and I'm concerned about where to subscribe to fetch my items on a screen.
Im using useEffect to dispatch the subscription to firebase db:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(userActions.fetchPets());
  }, []);
```

and inside the action

```
export const fetchPets = () => {
  return async dispatch => {
    const user = await firebase.auth().currentUser;
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref(`pets/${user.uid}`)
      .on("child_added", snapshot => {
        const pet = snapshot.val() || null;

        dispatch({ type: ADD_PET, payload: pet });
      });
  };
};
```

**My problem** is when my screen re-render this action executes again filling with repeated data.
This is my reducer:

```
case ADD_PET:
      return {
        ...state,
        pets: [...state.pets, action.payload]
      };
```

**My question**
Should I filter my state with key to delete repeated?
Should I put my subscription in another place? like a middleware or something? there is a pattern for this?

PS: "Sorry by my English"

Answer (score 0):

the pattern you are using is fine. 
If inside payload you have an array with new elements you have, your approach works fine. But, im assuming you are getting the same elements, just with any updated property. So, for example, if you have your pets store like this:

pets: [{id: 1, name: 'whatever'}], and your payload is : [{id: 1, name: 'whatever2'}], now you have both concatenated in your store, what is bad, because is the same object, updated.
So, if you will have the full list updated in the request, i would just change your reducer to this:

```
const initialState = { pets: [] };

case ADD_PET:
  return {
    ...state,
    pets: action.payload
  };
```

So everytime you make the api request, you will have the updated list of elements.

Another case is if you get in the request only the updated, and you will have to filter your object based on ids, and then just replace the updated ones. But i dont think it is your case.

Comment: the thing is that 

.on("child_added", snapshot => {
        const pet = snapshot.val() || null;

        dispatch({ type: ADD_PET, payload: pet });
      });
calls when 1 child is added, on the beginning fetch all data from firebase pets. but when 1 pet is added also execute chilled_aded so, I need the pets array and when a child is added, add it on a reducer.

Comment: With your approach I only get the last one on my reducer. Maybe I should move the fetchPets() to another place where can't be re executed, as useEffect do.